# Capitalize first letters string of words and add word to string

Tags: string, power-automate, toupper

I working a power automate flow and I've been struggling for quite a while to create a variable which I need to populate "County Name" in my word template. This flow allows a County staff member to fill out a form and then those MS Form responses dynamically populate in a word template. All of this works well but I'm struggling to create a variable which would populate "County Name" in my word template. I need the variable (dynamic content) to be able to capitalize the response from the MS Form

I need the dynamic content to be able to capitalize the name of County, so capitalize first word and second word. Example: "Washington County". I also need the variable to recognize when someone just puts "Washington" in the MS Form, instead of "Washington County", and then add County to the word template. I've tried quite a few combinations with toUpper and append string and not able to quite figure it out. Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion, look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.

There are a few ways to achieve what you're wanting but the easiest way is by using the `Transform` operation.

There are over **100** built-in functions that can be made use of through the framework and one of them is the `Proper` function.

It will also allow you to concatenate strings at the same time.  However, that process seems quite clunky for your requirement given how do you know if `County` should be added?  I'll leave that with you though.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/custom-functions/

(On the `String` tab, scroll down to the `Proper` function)

This is a basic example ...

[image: Flow]

You can see I've initialised a variable with the relevant value.

I've then configured the transform function (it takes an array of objects) to take in your data along with a transformation definition.

That definition runs a set of functions to get the result you need.  Rather than checking for `County` at the end, I just add it and then replace `County County` with `County`.

You can also see the `Proper` function in there, that's the key part that uppercases each word.

> This will be made easier in future as there is an `Evaluate` operation coming  and that will allow you to do it in much simpler terms.

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/c-script-evaluate/

That's looking to drop by the end of this month but is available now via the HTTP operation.

**Result (with "county" in the provided value)**

[image: Result 1]

**Result (without "county" in the provided value)**

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Hey Skin, thanks again for helping with this. I did find the Proper function and I don't think that works for Power Automate. I know it works for Power Apps but my understanding is that it doesn't work for Power Automate. When I used it, I got a 'Proper is not a valid function' error.

Comment: I've actually figured out that I don't need to do this because I've changed the way my data is collected. I do however have another question related to this same flow. It might be easier to ask it here than create a whole new question. I'm trying to set a Form response dynamic variable, like "County Name" and make it so the County name is tied to  the County abbreviation. Example is "Washington County": "WC". But I'm missing the dynamic variable portion of this if that makes sense. How did I tie this to the respone of "County Name" on the form?

Comment: Just to be clear, the functions I am talking about aren’t in PA, they’re in the advanced data operations connector, hence why you got an error saying proper doesn’t exist. It is all powerful and waaaaay more comprehensive than standard PA data operations and functions. You can see I’ve created a clear example that works with Proper so if you had’ve followed the links, you would see the supporting documentation behind how it works. Keep that connector in mind for future challenges you may have. Well done on fixing it at the source though, that’s always the best approach.

Comment: As for your other issue, I’d suggest raising another question, too hard to help without additional context.

Comment: Ahh Gotcha. I saw that there is a free trial for advanced data operations but you have to pay after that so I didn't pay for it. But that makes sense now.

Comment: Yes but it’s hell cheap.

Comment: Agreed. Not too bad!